# How do I properly create a datetime in php using variables and insert them into my table?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have several variables that each contain a string with a number value, here's a list of my variables and their supposed values:

```
$year = "2016";
$month = "4";
$day = "23";
$hour = "4";
$minute = "0";
```

I'm trying to use these values to create a datetime which I will insert into my table, my code so far is:

```
$new_date = new DateTime("".$year."-".$month."-".$date." ".$hour.":".$minute.":0");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO schedule (date) VALUES ($new_date)");
```

But I'm getting an error which is: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to format your date object and use the string for mysql insert

[PHP DateTime Format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
$new_date = new DateTime("".$year."-".$month."-".$date." ".$hour.":".$minute.":0");
$formatted = $new_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO schedule (date) VALUES ($formatted)");
```

Comment: Oddly enough, it doesn't seem to be working. If I click my button it doesn't insert it into my database. Out of curiousity, I tried to echo the $formatted variable's value and copied it and went into my phpmyadmin and manually added the exact same value through the phpmyadmin's insert menu but it surprisingly went in. I tried to copy the sql statement generated by the manual insert and replaced my current query with that statement but replaced the static datetime value copied off from the $formatted variable with $date2 but it isn't working. What could have been the cause?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I forgot to put the single quotations marks. Now it's working, thanks a lot!